# Selecting a preferred column only if it exists in DB2

Tags: sql, join, db2

I have the following 3 tables (ORDERS, SUPPLIERS and OUTSTANDING):

ORDERS
orderedQty
receivedQty
orderNumber
supplierId

SUPPLIERS
supplierId
orderNumber

OUTSTANDING
supplierId
productId
orderNumber
productId
updatedQty

I wish to select everything from ORDERS and an additional column named "shipping".

"Shipping" should contain the value in OUTSTANDING's updatedQty (if one exists) else it should return ORDERED's "orderedQty" value again as "shipping".

So far I have the following:

```
SELECT     ORDERS.orderedQty, ORDERS.orderNumber,                                                                                 
           ORDERS.productId, OUTSTANDING.updatedQty 

{SOME MAGIC HERE THAT CHECKS IF OUTSTANDING HAS a record ELSE RETURNS ORDERS' orderedQty as shipping}


FROM         ORDERS INNER JOIN                                                                                                    
              SUPPLIERS AS D ON ORDERS.supplierId = D.supplierId AND ORDERS.orderNumber = D.orderNumber INNER JOIN                
              OUTSTANDING ON ORDERS.supplierId = OUTSTANDING.supplierId AND ORDERS.orderNumber = OUTSTANDING.orderNumber AND      
              ORDERS.productId = OUTSTANDING.productId
```

Also please note I am confused as to the kind of join I should have used to bring in the OUTSTANDING table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't fully specify what it means for the value not to exist.  My assumption is that there is no match or the value is NULL.

Either way, you can get what you want using `COALESCE()`.  With this logic, I think `LEFT JOIN` is more appropriate.  This ensures that you get all the orders, even when there is no matching record in the other tables.

```
SELECT o.orderedQty, o.orderNumber, o.productId, os.updatedQty,
       COALESCE(os.updatedQty, o.orderedQty) as NewColumn
FROM ORDERS o LEFT JOIN                                                                                                    
     SUPPLIERS s 
     ON o.supplierId = s.supplierId AND o.orderNumber = s.orderNumber LEFT JOIN                
     OUTSTANDING os
     ON o.supplierId = os.supplierId AND o.orderNumber = os.orderNumber AND      
        o.productId = os.productId;
```